# I don't have compile_commands.json and clang file in vscode gdnative

Tags: visual-studio-code, godot, gdnative

problem: I tried to setup gdnative for ubuntu linux using by following this tutorial https://youtu.be/X1bKjzdZmTA, but when I was compiling headers i found that i don't have compile_commands.json or clang files. can someone tell me how to somehow install them individually.
things i tried: reinstalled it by using setup.sh but nothing changed.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but I believe this is what you need: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to create my own compile_commands.json because of that doc.